# Bootstrap Dropdown Navigation Toggle Not Working with native Joomla jQuery

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery, bootstrap, navigation

I'm trying to implement a Bootstrap menu with a toggle dropdown on a Joomla site.

Got most of it working except for the toggle isn't working...Looking at inspect tool when `.dropdown` element is clicked, the `.open` class is added very quickly, but then immediately disappears. Wondering if there's another script or something else that's causing issues.

I've added necessary classes and attributes via jQuery like so:

```
jQuery(".currenthas-child, .has-child").addClass("dropdown");
jQuery(".submenu").addClass("dropdown-menu");
jQuery(".menu").addClass("nav navbar-nav");

jQuery( ".dropdown > a:first-child" ).attr({
    'data-toggle': "dropdown",
    role: "button",
    'aria-haspopup': "true",
    'aria-expanded': "false"
});

jQuery(".dropdown > a:first-child").append('<span class="caret"></span>');
jQuery(".dropdown > a:first-child").addClass("dropdown-toggle");
```

Here's a [link to live staging site](http://cccaccessibility.mc2dev.com)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have 2 instances of jQuery being imported. One from Joomla's JUI folder and one from your template. You should disable the one from your template if possible. Multiple instances can cause conflicts

Comment: Why use jQuery to add classes to your elements? Why not just add classes to your elements?? 10x this for your Landmark roles, these should be in your markup, not appended with jQuery; that's not accessible in the least. This is not how #a11y is done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Comment out the following line in your template index.php:

```
jdoc:include type="head"
```

If this workaround works for your toggle, there is a conflict between the native joomla-js-library and your bootstrap-js-library.

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap must be enabled in joomla by standard method in template, see j.docs. You can improve it by external bootstrap css and js.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can imagine why someone else did.  This is a relatively unhelpful post.  When you have some valuable information to share, please do so in a thoughtful and articulate way that will truly benefit future researchers.